# R to read xlsx to construct corpus

Tags: r, xlsx, corpus

I intend to get Term-Document Matrix from hundreds of documents in .pdf and .xlsx.
I could construct corpus with following command to read lots of pdf files.

```
bb <- Corpus(DirSource(aa),readerControl=list(reader=readPDF))
```

And searched and failed to find how to read .xlsx to construct corpus in R.
I installed package and set library for 'xlsx' and 'rJava'.
Is there any way to read hundreds of xlsx files similarly with reading pdf files. (There are so many files, I cannot convert them to .csv one by one)

Comment: Please, when non-base functions are used, indicate the imported package(s) (e.g. `Corpus` belongs to tm package, right ?)

Comment: Sorry about that. you are right. Corpus is under tm package